# Parsing Incorrect Values When Reading Excel File in Go Language

Tags: excel, go, excelize

I'm working on a Go application where I need to parse dates from Excel files. The dates in Excel are in the format 27/06/1905, but when I use the Go `excelize` package to read, the date string value is `27-06-05`, and the resulting date after format with `time` package is `27-06-2005`, which doesn't match the Excel date.

I suspect this discrepancy is due to the default date format used by Excel and how the time package in Go interprets the date. Can someone help me understand how to correctly parse Excel date formats in Go?

I use `go 1.19` and `github.com/xuri/excelize/v2 v2.7.1`

Here's a simplified version of my code:

go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Open Excel file
    excelFile, _ := excelize.OpenFile(tc.filePath)

    // Creates a rows iterator for reading row by row
    rows, _ := excelFile.Rows("Asset Data")

    // Read the header row and convert to column map
    var cm columnMap
    if rows.Next() {
        headers, _ := rows.Columns()

        cm = convertExcelHeaderToColumnMap(headers)
    }

    // Read body
    rows.Next()
    row, err := rows.Columns()
    require.NoError(t, err)

    // value of row[DateOfGenerationIndex] is 27-06-05
    dateOfGeneration, err := time.Parse("01-02-06", row[DateOfGenerationIndex])

    fmt.Println(dateOfGeneration) // value of dateOfGeneration is 27-06-2005
}
```

I've tried adjusting the layout strings, but the resulting date doesn't match the Excel date.

Comment: We're going to be unable to help without an example Excel file + enough code to reproduce. The current example refers to undefined functions. If the data inside the file is actually like "27-06-05", then there's not an easy way to fix without implementing your own logic. The pivot year for two-digit dates is 1969: 69 -> 1969, 68 -> 2068.

Comment: The ideal solution is to convert the underlying data to use fully-qualified years. Two-digit dates are a pain for this specific reason.

Comment: @coxley thank you for your help. Apologies for the confusion. This file contains business-sensitive information, so I can't share it here. Fortunately, the client has confirmed an error in a specific column, where the displayed values are incorrect. I just need to update all the column values to 'General' and ensure it only displays the year '2005' for dates

Comment: Sounds like an easy fix after all. :)